# If anyone can help me because im stuck in count query in jsp (im new in databases )

Tags: mysql, jsp

I cant run this query i dont know why i thought it was correct but the select in jsp is returning nothin (also sorry for my bad english) im a student in highschool and not its not fo a project but fo educational purpose only.
Thank you for understanding.

String query = "select s_int,count(bio) from users,scientific_interests"

- " where scientific_interests.Record_number = users.Record_number"
- "and s_int = '"+SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS+"' ";

MYSQL DB  TABLES

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scientific_interests (

intId INT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT,

Record_number VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

s_int varchar(100) not null,

```
PRIMARY KEY (intId),


FOREIGN KEY(Record_number) references users(Record_number)
```

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (

```
Record_number VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,


name CHAR(50),


surname CHAR(50),


institute VARCHAR(50),


department VARCHAR(50),


bio VARCHAR(500),


b_day INT(10),


b_month INT(10),
```

b_year INT(10),

```
PRIMARY KEY (Record_number)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Try using a join:

```
 String query = "select s_int,count(bio) from scientific_interests JOIN users ON scientific_interests.Record_number = users.Record_number WHERE s_int = '"+SCIENTIFIC_INTRESTS+"' ";
```

Comment: thank you  very much  i try that later in this day :)